# How to set screen time out for an activity then turn back on when screen pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, timeout, runnable

I have an activity that works like a night time clock, the user can change certain preferences to edit screen brightness, background colour, text colour, etc.

At the moment the activity disables screen timeout and lockscreen, because the thread that updates the time on the screen runs every second (I may remove seconds and update less frequently to save further), it ends up using more battery than I'd like. The whole point of it is to act like a bedside clock, the user can easily tap a button for the time to light up, in this case that button is the screen.

What I want to do is turn off the screen after a certain amount of time (a preference in the application's settings) then listen for screen presses. When the user taps the screen it will turn the screen back on until it times out again or the user destroys the activity, at which point screen time out will default to their phones settings.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can already tell you that detecting touch events when the screen is off is not possible. There is a "workaround" of using the accelerometer to detect movement if the touch produces just enough movement to be detectable.

To programmatically turn the screen on/off:

```
PowerManager powermanager = ((PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
wakeLock = powermanager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
wakeLock.acquire();

...

if(wakeLock.isHeld()) {
    wakeLock.release();
}
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case, really the ultimate goal is to reduce battery consumption. Would you say that just fading out any views to a black activity and unregistering any receivers so nothing runs while the screen appears to be "off" would be enough?

Comment: I don't believe the color of the screen has much impact but instead I would focus on the backlight. You should be able to dim the device to the lowest possible setting and save greatly on power. Additionally, the removing of receivers and extending the time between when the thread that changes the UI gets fired (at least making it configurable to the user) might also notably reduce consumption but honestly I'm not an expert so I would just try different variations.

Comment: I'll give that a go, I've made it reduce brightness to 0.01, remove callbacks and unregister receivers. I'll just have to let it run for a while and check the battery usage. I'll let you know how it goes, cheers for the help.